# np.vectorize only size-1 arrays can be converted to scalars

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to print ROC curve evaluating my Bayes model

```
fpr, tpr, _ =roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)
```

Func:

```
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='Naive Bayes (AUROC = %0.3f)' % y_pred)

plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.legend()  
plt.show()
```

I receive error while plotting it.  Previous posts suggest to use  `np.vectorize`
Yet I tried `astype(int)` on my `fpr` and `tpr` here:

```
x = fpr.astype(int)
y = tpr.astype(int)
```

It still does not help

What is wrong here?  This is how fpr,tpr looked like before calling `astype`

[image]

Comment: Please post the full error trace, and the results (values) of `fpr` and `tpr` as *text*, *not* image (you know you can just copy-paste them from the Jupyter output cell, right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the values of `fpr` and `tpr` you show, `plot` works just fine:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fpr = np.array([0, 0.136, 1.])
tpr = np.array([0, 0.5, 1.])

plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The problem arises from the puzzling presence of `y_pred` in a place where it does not belong, i.e. in the `label` argument:

```
# dummy y_pred - exact values do not matter
y_pred = np.array([0.1, 0.34, 0.43, 0.89])

plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='Naive Bayes (AUROC = %0.3f)' % y_pred)
```

Result (unsurprizing):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-8-ccbf0542501c> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='Naive Bayes (AUROC = %0.3f)' % y_pred)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

It is puzzling why you try to use the predictions  `y_pred` in a place where you clearly imply you actually want the AUC score.

You should calculate the AUC separately, and use it in the appropriate place of your plot instead of `y_pred`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
AUC = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='Naive Bayes (AUROC = %0.3f)' % AUC)
```